# How can I build a Gradle plugin with Maven

Tags: maven, gradle

It's possible to build a Gradle plugin with Maven. Which dependencies are needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. We do so with [Spring Boot's Gradle plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.5.x/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin) using these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-core</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-base-services</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-base-services-groovy</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gradle</groupId>
    <artifactId>gradle-plugins</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Groovy's in Maven Central, but the Gradle dependencies are in their own repo: http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local

Comment: I see that you have recently (March 2017) [switched](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/9b15e6b5a3c0fc18372f532063bb43f25abcf984) from an all Maven build to a “Maven calls Gradle” variant. Can you please elaborate why. (I ask because I also want to build a Gradle plugin with Maven, but fail to find types like `org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet` in any Maven repository at http://repo.gradle.org/. Did you face similar problems?)

Comment: There were a few reasons. Some of the types we wanted to depend upon were not in modules in Gradle's repo. Downloading a Gradle distribution, extracting the jars we needed and publishing them somewhere ourselves was a pain. Using TestKit (which is awesome) proved nigh-on impossible. The new approach is working very well so far. I'd recommend it.