# Using a Gradle Plugin in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, javafx

I need to use this gradle plugin https://github.com/beryx/badass-runtime-plugin in my application in order to create a runtime image of my non modular Javafx application. The problem is that I'm using Maven and I don't know if there's anyway to use it with Maven.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thank you very much

Comment: i think you can do something like this [gradle-plugin-with-maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555560/how-can-i-build-a-gradle-plugin-with-maven)

Comment: I think it will do the job, but in the link you posted it doesn't explain how to build the gradle plugin with maven. I have made a quicksearch and all I can't find is the opposite (making a gradle plugin from a maven one).

Comment: Consider using the maven-javafx-plugin to create an image of the modular portions and also using the maven-assembly-plugin to copy the non-modular dependencies into the generated output, together with a shell script that places the non-modular dependencies on the classpath or modulepath.  That is a bit tricky to do but possible.  Alternatively use the ackman-jpackage-plugin to create an image using jpackage. Or switch to gradle if you want the exact functionality of the badass jlink or jpackage gradle plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is: can I apply a Gradle plugin to a consumer project using maven as build tool, the answer is: NO. These are two different build tools, plugins are not compatible each other.

You should either convert your maven project to gradle (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html ), or look for equivalent plugin in the maven ecosystem.

Comment: Finally I converted the project to gradle. Thank you